# Confused about package installtion options

Tags: ros, installation, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am really confused about all the options to install a package either from deb (ok, this not really confused about) or source.

I tried to figure out how to get the turtlebot simulator working on my current system (Ubuntu 14.04 ros-indigo gazebo_2_2).
So first I looked up the branches on the github repositories and found the indigo Branch ([Turtlebot-Indigo-Branch](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/tree/indigo)). So I tried to install this package but failed.
There is a .rosinstall file but i found in several other questions on answers.ros.org also a lot about rosmake, roslocate (which wont work for me somhow), local installtion of ros and so on and I got really confused ([The confusing link :)](http://answers.ros.org/question/10581/installing-ros-packages-from-source/))

On the other hand there are also a lot of packages which could be installed (?) like these ones [Packages which can be installed](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/)

So for now I am really really confused about all the installation methods and downloading the packages.

Maybe some find this a question for real freshmen but I am a little bit clueless with this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192243/confused-about-package-installtion-options/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2014-09-09**:
Do you want to install the complete ROS from source or just the turtlebot simulator?

PS: The answer in your link refers to using rosbuild. For indigo you will have to create a catkin workspace and build your from-source-package there: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-09-09**:
I already installed Ros via deb so i just want to run turtlebot simulator but I am actually looking for a general answer for installing packages and stacks.
Oh thanks i didnt notice this about rosbuild in the link.
I already did the tutorials but maybe i missed something with catkin workspaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a general rule of thumb, use the deb installation method.

Only build from source if you want to modify or debug the package or if you need an urgent bug fix.

If you need to install from source, clone the repository into your [catkin workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) source folder and do a catkin_make. Take care of the [dependencies](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep).

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-09-10**:
So far so good, but especially for turtlebot simulator i also need e.g. the turtlebot description which is not include in the source pacakge. So I just clone this aswell and do a catkin_make?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-10**:
Yes this is possible.